# JPA guice @Transactional not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, guice

I have followed below link to setup my service to hit DB with Hibernate with JPA and Guice. My code is also same as that of in the below link
http://www.benmccann.com/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice/

When I am persisting the updates to DB with @Transactional guice annotation, it is not persisting into DB. Starting the transaction and comiting it separately persists the data.

I have checked some other stackoverflow links where they are mentioning to use guice @Transaction annotation instead of javax. And handle EnitytManager injection by guice instead of creating.

I am already doing the same but still it is not working. Seems like I'm missing something else.

Comment: Could you post your code (service method and module config)?

Comment: It is same config as in http://www.benmccann.com/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice/
For persisting the data, Instead of beginning the transaction and commiting it later, trying it to work with @Transactional annotation.

Comment: Well, if it's the same config, there is no support for `@Transactional` included in the sample code, why would you assume it would work? Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should take a look at this: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JPA